# ¿Por qué me salta este error con la libreria PySFTP?

Tags: python, sftp

```
 # Listar el directorio con formato de Servidor
    for attr in directory_structure:
        coincidencias = re.search(patronFinal, attr.filename)
        print ("ficheros           ------------------------------------->    " + attr.filename +'\n')

        # Sacamos por pantalla las coincidencias
        if coincidencias:
            print ("coincidencias  buena          ------------------------------------->    " + attr.filename +'\n')
            sftp.get( attr.filename, rutaDescarga ,preserve_mtime = True )
```

El error me salta justo despues de la linea sftp.get

Error que me da:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pruebas_Arrays.py", line 230, in <module>
    conexionFtp(elemento[0],elemento[1],elemento[2],elemento[3],elemento[4],elemento[5],elemento[6], marcaTiempo)
  File "Pruebas_Arrays.py", line 196, in conexionFtp
    sftp.get( attr.filename, rutaDescarga ,preserve_mtime = True )
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 249, in get
    self._sftp.get(remotepath, localpath, callback=callback)
  File "C:\Users\becario2adm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 801, in get
    with open(localpath, "wb") as fl:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\becario2adm\\Downloads\\test\\'
```

Comment: "No such file or directory" -> no encuentra el fichero

Comment: supongo queno encuentra  el fichero para descargar o lo que no encuentra es el directorio de descarga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente lo que no encuentra es la carpeta donde se supone que ha de guardar el fichero. El fichero en sí puede no existir y eso no sería problema, pues al abrirlo en modo escritura se crearía uno nuevo.

Puedes verificar si la carpeta existe (y si no es así crearla) con el código siguiente:

```
import os
if not os.path.exists(rutaDescarga):
    os.makedirs(rutaDescarga)
```

La función `makedirs()` se asegura de crear rutas intermedias si fuera necesario. Es decir, por ejemplo en tu caso la ruta que da el problema es `C:\Users\becario2adm\Downloads\test\`. Puede ser que simplemente falte la carpeta `test` dentro de `Donwloads`, pero también pudiera ser que directamente no existiera `becario2adm`. El método `makedirs()` creará todas las carpetas necesarias para asegurarse de que la ruta existe.

Por supuesto fallará si al crear alguna de las carpetas no tienes permisos (por ejemplo, si la carpeta a crear está en la cuenta de otro usuario, o si intentas crear directorios en carpetas de sistema o en las que no tengas permisos de escritura). Pero frente a esto nada puede hacerse.